# Splitting field of $f$ as smallest field extension containing all BUT ONE zero of $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm just working with splitting fields and I have to prove something which I don't understand.

Let $L$ be a splitting field of the polynomial $f$ over $K$ and $f = \prod_{i=1}^n(X-\alpha_i)$.

Prove: $L = K(\alpha_1, …, \alpha_{n-1})$ (so one alpha less!)

By definition we have $L = K(\alpha_1, …, \alpha_{n-1}, \alpha_{n}) \subset K(\alpha_1, …, \alpha_{n-1})$. 
That means we have to show that $\alpha_n \in K(\alpha_1, …, \alpha_{n-1})$, but I don't know why that should be the case?

Comment: How can you have all but one zero of $f$ without also having the last one? Isn't the polynomial $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(X-\alpha_i)$ a factor of $f$? What is the other factor?

Comment: The way I see it it doesn't have to be a factor of $f$ in $K(\alpha_1, …, \alpha_{n-1})[X]$, while it obviously must be in $L[X]$, and then the other factor is $X - \alpha_n$. But that factor doesn't necessarily have to exist in $K(\alpha_1, …, \alpha_{n-1})[X]$ just as it doesn't have to in $K[X]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that **over** $\;L':=K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{n-1})\;$ :

$$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (X-\alpha_i)\cdot g(x)\;,\;\;g(x)\in L'[x]$$

but **it must be** that $\;g(x)=X-\alpha_n\;$ , so we've no option but to deduce that $\;\alpha_n\in L'\;$ and we're done.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. Since $f(x), \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(x-a_i) \in L'[x]$ we have $g(x) \in L'[x]$. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative point of view:

Write $f(X) = X^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$, where $a_i \in K$ by definition. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i=-a_{n-1}$ so clearly $\alpha_n=-a_{n-1}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha_i$ , which gives us what we want.